# How do you make Visual Studio Code's java extension recognize ANTLR4 source code packages?

Tags: java, maven, visual-studio-code, antlr, antlr4

How do you make Visual Studio Code's java extension recognize ANTLR4 source code packages? I installed the Maven extension in VSCode, which detected Java dependencies by itself. But it is still not enough. There are classes like

```
import org.antlr.v4.parse.ANTLRParser;
```

[image: import problem]

that are not accepted by the extension. A similar thing happens for packages. See:

[image: package problem]

Comment: The problem in your screenshot is actually true. You are trying to define a package different from your folder structure, that's wrong and would throw an error in Eclipse as well. Can you actually share the exact problem with the import? Since my guess is that it is the same problem.

Comment: I'll post a screen shot for the import. As for the package and folder structure, I haven't changed the repository at all and just forked it from the antlr project.

Answer (score 0):

Try to install the dependencies from net,open your `pom.xml` then add below dependency :

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.antlr</groupId>
  <artifactId>antlr4-maven-plugin</artifactId>
  <version>4.8-1</version>
</dependency>
```

or you could press `F1` > `Maven :add a dependency` >select your project  >input `org.antlr` > select `antlr4-maven-plugin`